# “Info.plist” couldn’t be removed

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, info.plist

I use GoogleMaps framework for my private pod library, while GoogleMaps is integrated as `vendored_frameworks` in my podspec. When I build my main app project with above library as a pod dependency, build errors as follows:

> CopyPlistFile /Users/hennessy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Skywalker-fztqebjjkaudzjemlimlwketivsw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ZLBS/ZLBS.framework/Info.plist /Users/hennessy/Projects/Skywalker_ios/ZLBS/ZLBS/Vendor/Google/GoogleMaps.framework/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle/Info.plist
>       cd /Users/hennessy/Projects/Skywalker_ios/Pods
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       builtin-copyPlist --convert binary1 --outdir /Users/hennessy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Skywalker-fztqebjjkaudzjemlimlwketivsw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ZLBS/ZLBS.framework -- /Users/hennessy/Projects/Skywalker_ios/ZLBS/ZLBS/Vendor/Google/GoogleMaps.framework/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle/Info.plist
>
> error: failed to remove /Users/hennessy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Skywalker-fztqebjjkaudzjemlimlwketivsw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ZLBS/ZLBS.framework/Info.plist: “Info.plist” couldn’t be removed.

I googled for solutions such as clean and remove derived data, but nothing helps. What went wrong? How can I fix it? I use Swift 3.2 and Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Check the permissions on /Users/hennessy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Skywalker-fztqebjjkaudzjemlimlwketivsw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ZLBS/ZLBS.framework/Info.plist and its origin